# How to append same string to multi pdf name files

Tags: file, shell, batch-file

I have a bunch of files and I need to append a string to the end of their names. I tried few thing, but they didn't work for me.

Example for what I want:

```
 aaa.pdf   ----->  aaa2016
 bbb.pdf   ----->  bbb2016
 ccc.pdf   ----->  ccc2016
```

I need some batch or something like that that do it. Any ideas for my problem?

Comment: please show what you tried and what is the logic here. Otherwise, this is too broad. Please check [ask].

Comment: i tried to work with excel and vbs, i'm looking for simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the batch program that rename your files as your wish.

You have to execute with two arguments, First arg is the directory where your files exist and other is the string that you need to append with all files

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
echo "usage : script currentDir appendString"
exit 1
fi

for x in `ls $1/*.pdf`; do
fileName=`echo $x | sed "s/.pdf//g"`
fileName=`echo "${fileName}${2}"`
mv  $x $fileName

done
```

for x in `ls $1/*.pdf`; do -- Is to read all files with extension 'pdf'
these two lines are to frame new name with the string you provided as argument

fileName=`echo $x | sed "s/.pdf//g"`
fileName=`echo "${fileName}${2}"`

and finally 'mv' command will rename the files as per your desired name

Comment: The [batch-file] tag implies that he's using Windows.

Comment: Oops, Sorry, Since it also had shell. I gave this script

Comment: To be fair, if he's using Windows 10 or has Cygwin installed, this answer could still be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk Rename Console is the version of Bulk Reneme for command line
http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Command.php

Comment: thanks you. it's working.